# Calling c++ from fortran

Tags: c++, interface, fortran

I want to call a function which is both in a c++ parent class "inval" and in the c++ derived class "SMval", from Fortran. The function I want to call is included in a bigger code which I would like to interface to my fortran. I have written the following code (3 files)

In library_wrapper.h:

```
#include "classes.h"
#include "SMval.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus 
//Forward declarations of classes 
class inval; 
class SMval;

extern "C" { 
#endif

void* createinval_(); 
void destroyinval_(void* instance); 
void* createSMval_(); 
void destroySMval_(void* instance); 
void invalsetWrapper_(const int idx, const double val); 
void SMvalsetWrapper_(const int idx, const double val); // Declaration of the wrapper function

#ifdef __cplusplus } 
#endif
```

In library wrapper.cpp:

```
#include "library_wrapper.h" 
#include "classes.h" 
#include "SMval.h" 
#include "Cplx.h"
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h>

extern "C" {
void* createinval_() {
    return new inval();
}

void* createSMval_() {
    return new SMval();
}

void destroyinval_(void* instance) {
     delete static_cast<inval*>(instance);
}

void destroySMval_(void* instance) {
    delete static_cast<SMval*>(instance);
}

void invalsetWrapper_(const int idx, const double val) {
    inval obj;
    return obj.set(idx, val);
}

void SMvalsetWrapper_(const int idx, const double val) {
    SMval obj;
    return obj.set(idx, val);
}

}
```

and finally the main fortran:

```
   PROGRAM main
   implicit none
   CALL CREATEINVAL()
   CALL CREATESMVAL()
   CALL INVALSETWRAPPER(12, 1/137.03599976)
   CALL SMVALSETWRAPPER(1, 91.1876)
   END
```

I am compiling on MAC Sonoma:

```
clang++ -g -std=c++11 -c library_wrapper.cpp
ld -r allothersobjectfiles.o library_wrapper.o -o combined_library.o
clang++ -shared -o liblibrary.a combined_library.o
gfortran -ffixed-line-length-none fortran.f -o main -L. -llibrary
```

But I get

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
  _createinval_, referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccPLQP9I.o
  _createsmval_, referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccPLQP9I.o
  _invalsetwrapper_, referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccPLQP9I.o
  _smvalsetwrapper_, referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ccPLQP9I.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to create a static library and link it, but it is still not working

Comment: Why do you ask about Fortran 77, when the example program you show isn't an F77 program and the compiler you are using isn't an F77 compiler?

Comment: To do that as properly as possible, you should use the C/Fortran interoperabilty features of Fortran, based on the `iso_c_binding` Fortran module

Comment: I am using gfortran and the sample fortran code should contain the declaration of variables following fortran 77, not 90.

Comment: Why must you adhere to a 50+ year Fortran standard that has been superceded by 6 revisions?  If you must use Fortran 77, then you cannot do what you want.  First, `implicit none` is not F77.  Second, your subroutine names exceed six characters/digits.  Good luck.

Comment: @Clara Fixed source form is not necessarily Fortran77. It is still valid to this day and can be used with all the modern features of modern Fortran. So just because your Fortran is in Fixed source form does *not* mean it is Fortran77, and your example, as other say, most certainly isn't - mixed cased is another reason why it isn't.

Comment: @IanBush yeah, for several years I wrote fixed form fortran in F90 (former Compaq compiler). By look of it, compiler expects and specific calling conventions and it was compiler dependant. Modern way is somewhat similar to Lahey's of that time

Answer (score 1):

To do that as properly as possible, you should use the C/Fortran interoperabilty features of Fortran, based on the iso_c_binding Fortran module

For instance, to call the `invalsetWrapper_` function, your Fortran code should look like:

```
program main
   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none

   interface
      subroutine inval_set_wrapper(idx,val) bind(C,name="invalsetWrapper_")
         import c_int, c_double
         integer(kind=c_int), value :: idx
         real(kind=c_double), value :: val
      end subroutine
   end interface

   !...

   call inval_set_wrapper(12, 1/137.03599976d0)

end
```

Note that the interoperability assumes the use of pairs of compilers (that is, you should use `gcc` along with `gfortran`), even if it often works when mixing compilers (but without any guarantee).

Comment: Can you correct the example here to be compilable? Equally, there doesn't seem to be much point using `integer(c_int)` in the interface if later on it's assumed that the interoperable integer is the default integer.

Comment: I am sorry, isn't this work for fortran 90 only?

Comment: @Clara What's the problem with Fortran 90 ? You are using gfortran, which can compile almost any code that complies to the Fortran 2018 standard. Why would you want to use only F77 features?

Comment: @francescalus At least, in the uncommon cases where `integer(c_int)` is not the defaut integer, there will be a clear compilation error instead of going silently wrong at execution.

Comment: "To do that as properly as possible" one can write code that doesn't make "compilation error" assumptions.

Comment: @Clara, the example code is not valid Fortran 90.  You need at least Fortran 2003.